Why do the Moppets go back to wearing their pupae costumes?
In The Venture Brothers, after the Monarch and Dr. Girlfriend get married, their henchmen merge together. This leads to the Moppets joining as "The Pupae twins" with costumes that look like weird caterpillars.  Later on we see them pop out of their uniforms into costumes similar to the rest of the Monarch's henchmen.  However this only happens in one scene in one episode, as they immediately go back to their previous uniforms until they are removed from the show.  Was there any explanation about why their costumes were changed and then reverted?
